# Is there any way to make my blogspot page accesible using www.blogname,blogspot.com

Tags: blogger

I have recently published a blogspot page related to my forthcoming wedding. I'd rather not disclose the specific url but it's published with the url as the standard format

http://blogname.blogspot.com

Unfortunately the wedding invitations with the link to the blog have been sent out with the link in the format

http://www.blogname.blogspot.com

Some recipients report that when using the www link as per the invitation that the page does not work due to security errors, which I can verify.

Is there any way that I can amend the blog so that it is visible using the www. link ? Invitations have already been sent so I cannot really point the site at any other domain.

Thanks

Comment: In the Settings tab, look for personalized redirect, sorry english not my language so it might say diferent but it's where you also set up a custom 404 (error) page. You can add the url as it is written in your invites and make redirect to the correct one in your blog.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try